# How can I dump data into more than 2 textfields with one suggestion? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to autofill several textfields with one suggestion, like for example: If I select Washington as a state where I live I want the other field that would be country field to fill itself with U.S.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: get selected state value and fetch related country value for the selected state value from database or some other place. fill the country text field with the fetched country value. its depends on your program design

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `setState( )` inside the `onChanged`. inside that `setState`, you will change the value of the other field `otherDropdownValue` . Here is a small example with dropDownMenus.

Dont forget you need a `StatefulWidget` (not `StateLess`)

**Code:**

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String dropdownValue = 'One';
  String otherDropdownValue = 'Two';

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            //******************************************
            //*****Here is what you are looking for*****
            //******************************************
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = newValue;
              otherDropdownValue = newValue; ///Changes the other one
            });
            },
          items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: value, child: Text(value),);}).toList(),
        ),
      DropdownButton<String>(
        value: otherDropdownValue,
        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
          setState(() {
            otherDropdownValue = newValue; 
          });
        },
        items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: value, child: Text(value),);}).toList(),
      ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if this does not help?

**EDIT to answer your last comment:**

Same logic to apply with a `TextField` or a `textformfield`.
You will need to add a `TextEditingController()` to control the text displayed.
Below is a fully working example (the part you need to look at is at the end)

and here is a link that explains the code (note I adjusted the code for your specific use case)

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Retrieve Text Input',
      home: MyCustomForm(),
    );
  }
}

// Define a custom Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

// Define a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the Form.
class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a text controller and use it to retrieve the current value
  // of the TextField.
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Start listening to changes.
    myController.addListener(_printLatestValue);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree.
    // This also removes the _printLatestValue listener.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _printLatestValue() {
    print('Second text field: ${myController.text}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ///********************
            ///**** LOOK HERE  ****
            ///********************
            TextField(
              onChanged: (text) {
                myController.text = text;
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: myController,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your attention, but I think I didn't explain myself well. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can you describe what do you need exactly?  Happy to help

Comment: do you still need this?

Comment: Ok, actually after thinking for a while, this is really clever, just that I need that in a textformfield.

Comment: Sure. I edited my previous answer and provided a fully working example. Hopefully this closes this question?

Comment: Yeah, I will be working with it in this week, thanks for your attention.